# How to save a resized image in Python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

Maybe this is because I'm a newby to Python. But I don't seem to be able to resize and save images.

Can somebody help me by telling me what I'm doing wrong here? I'm resizing first, and secondly cropping an image to 256x256. The output is saved as the original image. Function call like: `resizeAndCrop("path/to/image.png")`

Current behavior is the script saving the image in the original size...

```
# function for resizing and cropping to 256x256
def resizeAndCrop(imgPath):

    im = Image.open(imgPath)

    # remove original
    os.remove(imgPath)

    # Get size
    x, y = im.size

    # New sizes
    yNew = 256
    xNew = yNew # should be equal

    # First, set right size
    if x > y:
        # Y is smallest, figure out relation to 256
        xNew = round(x * 256 / y)
    else:
        yNew = round(y * 256 / x)

    # resize
    im.resize((int(xNew), int(yNew)), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)

    # crop
    im.crop(((int(xNew) - 256)/2, (int(yNew) - 256)/2, (int(xNew) + 256)/2, (int(yNew) + 256)/2))

    # save
    print("SAVE", imgPath)
    im.save(imgPath)
```

Comment: `resize()` returns a resized *copy* of an image, so you need to assign the result of the operation otherwise the new image is lost.  The same is true of `crop()` with the added wrinkle that "This is a lazy operation. Changes to the source image may or may not be reflected in the cropped image. To get a separate copy, call the `load` method on the cropped copy."

Comment: so you are performing crop and resize on the image, but nothing is happening and the same image as the original is being saved?

Comment: As in: `newImage = im.resize((int(xNew),.......` ?

Comment: @The4thIceman correct

Comment: then yeah @StevenRumbalski has it right I would say. you would need to assign it to a new variable

Comment: @BobvanLuijt:  Yes, as in `newImage = im.resize(...`  Or even `im = im.resize(...`

Comment: are you using PIL? out of curiosity

Comment: Aha, yes this works. Thank you gentleman... If somebody adds an answer I can mark it solved and that somebody scores some points... :-)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski was first. I defer to him

Comment: And yes, PIL. You can see the whole thing here: https://github.com/bobvanluijt/youtube-labeled-dataset-screenshot-downloader

Comment: @The4thIceman:  Go ahead.  I'm busy.  :)  I got my info from http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm, but it may be more updated to get info from https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation: https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/4.0.x/reference/Image.html

calling resize on an image "Returns a resized copy of this image." So you would need to assign the result to a new variable:

```
resizedImage = im.resize((int(xNew), int(yNew)), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```

and for cropping the same applies, but it is noted in the docs that "Prior to Pillow 3.4.0, this was a lazy operation." So nowadays you will need to assign the call to crop to another variable as well